# Compare issue in yii

Tags: yii

In almost in every wiki simple things are explained. I'm stuck in yii's `CDbcriteria` compare issue.

Only the exact "equal to" match is explained 
for:

```
select * from users where status ='active'
```

This comparison is explained:

```
$criteria->compare('status','active');
```

But I can't find an example script which describes it with an operator based search. Like not equal to for the following query:

```
select * from users where status !='active'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: i've logged in just to vote +1 this. no idea why people are downvoting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try some thing like this

```
$criteria->condition = " status<>'active'";
$criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
```

Answer (score 4):

`$criteria->addNotInCondition('status', array('active'));`

if `count(array('active')) === 1` sql will `status != 'active'`, else `status NOT IN ('active', 'smth else')`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$criteria->addCondition("NOT status = 'active'");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the below 3 conditions and it works like a charm:

```
$criteria->condition='employee_id<>:employee_id AND vehicle_id=:vehicle_id AND checked_in_on IS NULL';
            $criteria->params=array(':employee_id'=>Yii::app()->session['activity']->employee_id,':vehicle_id'=>$model->id);
            $checkedOutVehicleBySomeoneElse = Activity::model()->find($criteria);
```